# I'm trying to Intent number activity from main activity.The app stops working when i run

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In activity_main.xml, I have created a TextView,EditText and Button.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter the number"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/edit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="click here"
        android:onClick="VehicleNum"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When i click the Button, it wil call "VehicleNum" method. Here i'm calling NumberActicity through intent.After running the code in device, when i click the button, the app just stops working. Help me out.

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void VehicleNum(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NumberActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

*list_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvAnimals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Number.java*

```
public class Number {
    private Integer mNum;

    public Number(Integer nNum){
        mNum = nNum;
    }

    public Integer getmNum(){
       return mNum;
    }
}
```

*NumberActivity.java*

```
public class NumberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        ArrayList<Number> gokul = new ArrayList<>();
        int low = 0, high = 999;
        int num;
        int res;


        EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        int val = Integer.parseInt( edit.getText().toString() );
        for (int number = low; number <= high; ++number) {
            num = remind(number);
            if (num > 9) {
                res = remind(num);
                if (res == val) {
                    gokul.add(new Number(number));
                }
            } else {
                if (num == val) {
                    gokul.add(new Number(number));
                }
            }

        }NumberAdapter adapter = new NumberAdapter(this,gokul);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_number);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public int remind(int num){
        int result = 0;
        while (num != 0) {
            int remainder = num % 10;
            result += remainder;
            num /= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

*list_item.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text=" "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*NumberAdapter.java*

```
public class NumberAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Number> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = NumberAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    public NumberAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Number> gokul) {
        super(context,0,gokul );
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView==null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        }
        Number currentNumberActivty = getItem(position);
        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        miwokTextView.setText(currentNumberActivty.getmNum());
        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

*Logcat*

2021-01-02 16:15:55.971 9161-9161/com.example.recyclerview E/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.recyclerview, PID: 9161
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.recyclerview/com.example.recyclerview.Number}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2020)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1679)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4651)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4609)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4970)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4938)
at com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity.VehicleNum(MainActivity.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
2021-01-02 16:15:56.018 9161-9161/com.example.recyclerview I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9161 SIG: 9

Comment: Please add the logcat error.

Comment: I have added logcat error